# Why equality without type coercion return false for ===

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

### Why equality without type coercion return false?

The 3 equal signs mean "equality without type coercion". Using the triple equals, the values must be equal in type as well : [Reference](http://longgoldenears.blogspot.com/2007/09/triple-equals-in-javascript.html')

---

But here `new String()===new String()` both values and types are same. But Why this statement returns false?

Comment: `new String()` creates a string object and `===` operator compares the object by references therefore they are not equal

Comment: @abhishekkannojia please make that into an answer. :)

Comment: Perfectly summed up by @abhishekkannojia, if you do want to check objects for equality have a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201183/how-to-determine-equality-for-two-javascript-objects)

Comment: I'm not a javascript programmer nor C#, but I assume that === equality means same object as well. You allocate memory twice - there are two different objects and they have different address in memory. That's why === returns false.